# Stop propagation cancel button UISearchBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a navigation bar with added searchbar icon.
Tapping the searchbar button instantiates the UISearchBarController.

Everything works fine, except that the 'Cancel' button tap propagates to the navigation bar button below (which closes the current modal).

Tapping cancel here:

[image]

Also taps done here:

[image]

I've witnessed that there is a delegate method available:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

}
```

How do I stop the event from propagating?

Note: The propagation doesn't happen when tapping 'Cancel' after text was entered in the searchbar, only when it is empty. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are seeing is that tapping `Cancel` when text is present is actually clearing out the text within the `UITextField` that the `UISearchBar` owns (as part of the `UISearchController`). Tapping `Cancel` otherwise is supposed to dismiss the search bar. From the Apple docs on [`searchBarCancelButtonClicked:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624314-searchbarcancelbuttonclicked) it states that:

> Typically, you implement this method to dismiss the search bar.

I've ran into this in the past with "search bar" functionality on a `UITableViewController`, and it's one of the reasons why I've switched over to using a standard `UIViewController` which owns a `UITableView` and owns a `UISearchBar`. I have a little bit more control, this way, over the content of my view controller, and the search bar I'm using with it.

Not sure if that directly helps you, but using a `UISearchBar` instead of a `UISearchController` might point you in a better direction like it did for me.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this would complicate things unnecessarily, given that everything works perfectly otherwise. Not sure about your assumptions, tapping cancel dismisses the modal, which is done by the 'done' button. The cancel button effectively hides the search bar and acts as intended when text is typed in the searchbar.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the emulator fixed the problem, whatever that makes sense.